# CSS Dropdown Menu items go horizontally

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I searched on stackoverflow for this issue, but I couldn't find anything.

I've been working on a dropdown menu in CSS. When you hover your mouse over the dropdown menu, the dropdown items are showing up horizontally instead of vertically.

HTML

```
<div id="header">header
<ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a></a>Biografie</a></li>
    <li><a>Foto's</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">Meer
        <ul>
            <li><a>tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a>inhuren</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    /*header*/
#header {
    background-color: #5c931f;
}

#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header li {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #808080;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#header li:hover {
    color: blue;
}
/*dropdown menu*/
.dropdown ul{
    display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

How do I get my dropdown list items vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actively declared `li` to display `inline` here:

```
#header li {
...
display: inline;
...
}
```

Inline means, basically, "don't force wrap to next line." Take that out and it should go back to `block` behavior.

Edit: previously I didn't notice the nested `li`.

Add:

```
#header .dropdown li {
    display: block;
}
```

Alternatively, only target the direct child `li` with inline (note this would affect all styles applied to `li`:

```
#header > ul > li {
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline;
background-color: #000;
color: #808080;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, when I set the display to block, the whole header gets vertically. I want the header list items horizontally, but the dropdown list items vertically.

Comment: See my edit, I didn't notice the nested li. Just target the dropdown `li` with `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

Add/Change the following code:

```
.dropdown ul li{
     display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover ul{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/kr2jw577/

It does need some tweaking though.